# Using Web.Config from my mvc3 app under the test

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Is there a way how to use web.config from my project that us under the test.
I have in mind something dynamically coping the file into my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use VS build events. Assuming you want to copy web.config from your webapp project to test project you can try something like this:

1. Select your **Test project** and open its properties window (Alt + Enter)
2. Navigate to **Build events** tab
3. Edit **Pre-build event command line** textbox to following line:

> `copy "$(SolutionDir)MyWebApp\web.config" "$(TargetDir)"`

Command above will take *web.config* file from your *MyWebApp* project in *solution directory* and copy it to current project's (Test) target directory (which should be `\bin`).

Now, everytime you build your test project, web.config will be copied to its target directory.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what info from web.config you need in your test project. However, the need for a config file is usually a smell that you actually do integration testing rather than unit testing.